# how to change array scheme result of a query?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, oop, mysqli

```
class user{

protected $permissions;

public function can( $permission )
    {
        if (!isset($this->permissions)) {
            /*
             fetch permissions for this user from the database, and set the
             User::permissions property, to allow caching.
             */
            $cnx = $this->connexion();
            $stmt = $cnx->prepare('SELECT permissions.permission_name FROM permissions, users_permissions WHERE users_permissions.user_id = ? AND users_permissions.permission_id = permissions.permission_id');
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION["user_id"]);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->get_result();

            $people = array("Peter", "Joe", "Glenn", "Cleveland");
            var_dump($people);
            $this->permissions= $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);    

            var_dump($this->permissions);    
        }

        return in_array($permission, $this->permissions);
    }
}
```

(scheme 1) the result of the array looks like this :

```
array (size=8)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'permission_name' => string 'Peut créer une permission' (length=26)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'permission_name' => string 'Peut modifier une permission' (length=28)
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'permission_name' => string 'Peut voir des comptes utilisateurs' (length=34)
```

i tried `fetch_array` instead of `fetch_all` but it returns only one row

(scheme 2) is there anyway to make that array look like this one because if it does it will work :

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'Peter' (length=5)
  1 => string 'Joe' (length=3)
  2 => string 'Glenn' (length=5)
```

instantiate a user

```
$that_guy = new user();
if ( $that_guy->can('Peut créer une permission')) {
  echo"yay";
}else {
  echo"you can't";
}
```

is there any possible way to change the array of scheme 1 and make it look like array of scheme 2 ?

Comment: it's not clear where the actual problem is!? What does not work as expected?

Comment: for the last code i always have to use loop to get the permission_name i want the first code as it is to be converted to mysqli

Comment: why don't you filter that already in your sql?

Comment: or you flip the returned array to get `$permissions = Array('edit'=>true, 'read'=>true, 'delete'=>false)`

Comment: I think you can replace:

    `$result = $stmt->get_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($user_id);

    $stmt->store_result();

    while($t=$stmt->fetch()){
       $result[]=$t;
    }

    return $result;`

with `return $stmt->fetchAll();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the array

```
public function can( $permission )
        {
            if (!isset($this->permissions)) {

                $cnx = $this->connexion();
                $stmt = $cnx->prepare('SELECT permissions.permission_name FROM permissions, users_permissions WHERE users_permissions.user_id = ? AND users_permissions.permission_id = permissions.permission_id');
                $stmt->bind_param('s', $_SESSION["user_id"]);
                $stmt->execute();

                $result = $stmt->get_result();
                $stmt->bind_result($permission_name);
                $stmt->store_result();


                $this->permissions = array();
                while(($row = $result->fetch_assoc())) {
                    $this->permissions[] = $row['permission_name'];
                }


            }

            return in_array($permission, $this->permissions);
        }
```

the result will look like what you want in (scheme 2)

Comment: thank you i have tried your solution and it worked like charm looping through it does the trick

Answer (score 1):

With mysqli it's impossible, and this is a very good reason why you should use  PDO instead

```
$cnx = $this->connexion();
$stmt = $cnx->prepare('SELECT permissions.permission_name FROM permissions, users_permissions WHERE users_permissions.user_id = ? AND users_permissions.permission_id = permissions.permission_id');
$stmt->execute([$_SESSION["user_id"]]);
$this->permissions = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

That's all.
Not only this code is two times shorter, but also it is giving you the exact result you want.

Answer (score 0):

On PHP side you can use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$this->permissions = array_column($this->permissions, 'permission_name');
```

Also, I would use [`array_flip`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) additionally:

```
$this->permissions = array_flip(
    array_column($this->permissions, 'permission_name')
);
```

This way you can use `isset($this->permissions[$permission])` instead of `in_array($permission, $this->permissions);` as it is faster.